# Can states on commutative Banach algebras be understood as probability measures?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, banach-algebras

Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ is a commutative Banach algebra (over $\mathbb{R}$) or commutative Banach *-algebra (over $\mathbb{C}$). Is there always a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ such that there is a bijective correspondence between states (positive linear functionals of norm 1) on $\mathcal{A}$ and probability measures on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ together with a map $f:\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{A}$ such that $$\mu(\Delta)=\phi(f(\Delta))$$ for all $\Delta\in\mathcal{F}$ where $\mu$ is the probability measure corresponding to the state $\phi$?

If $\mathcal{A}$ is a C*-algebra the answer is yes. The measurable space is obtained by using the Gelfand transform establishing an isometry between $\mathcal{A}$ and $C_0(\Omega)$. The correspondence between states and probability measures is obtained by using Riesz' representation theorem. This construction no longer works in the general case though because now the Gelfand representation need not be an isometry. But this of course does not rule out a positive answer to the above question.

Comment: What properties do you want the correspondence to have? I imagine if you ask too much there are difficulties with examples like $A = \mathbb{C}[x]/x^2$ (equipped with some norm, it doesn't really matter which).

Comment: In the usual correspondence for C*-algebras you get moreover that the elements of $A$ correspond to random variables and evaluating a state on an element of $A$ corresponds to taking its expectation. But a nilpotent element of a commutative Banach algebra can't faithfully correspond to a random variable on any measurable space in a way compatible with multiplication.

Comment: As Qiaochu and Francois have pointed out, you need to specify what you mean by a state on a commutative Banach algebra. (There is a kind of definition in Bonsall and Duncan's book which might be appropriate, but I really think it is up to the person asking the question to specify what they mean in the question.)

Comment: If A is a Banach algebra over $\mathbb{R}$, then with a state I mean a linear functional $\phi:A\to\mathbb{R}$ of norm 1 with $\phi(a^2)\geq0$ for all $a$.
If it is an algebra over $\mathbb{C}$, then implicitly I assumed it to be a *-algebra.

Comment: For the correspondence I have in mind a bijection between states and probability measures together with the existence of an additive map $f:\mathcal{F}\to A$ such that $P(\Delta)=\phi(f(\Delta))$ for every $\Delta\in\mathcal{F}$ with $\phi$ the state associated with the probability measure $P$

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification (for future reference, to an analyst a Banach algebra does not automatically come with an involution!). I have voted to re-open; perhaps you could edit your question to include the information in your first comment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. The Gelfand space and transform you mention are defined for any commutative **Banach algebra** $A$, as $A^\dagger=\{$nonzero linear functionals $\chi:A\to\mathbf C:\chi(ab)=\chi(a)\chi(b)\}$ and $\hat a(\chi)=\chi(a)$.
2. On the other hand, the definition of a *state* $m$ on $A$ asks that $m$ be positive ($m(a^*a)\geqslant 0$) and so requires that your $A$ be at least a **$^*$-algebra**, right?
3. Now, is it a **Banach $^*$-algebra**, i.e. $\|a^*\|=\|a\|$? If so and $\smash{\hat A := \{\chi\in A^\dagger:\chi(a^*)=\overline{\chi(a)}\}}$ then one has what you want ([Fell-Doran](http://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=936628), p. 492):

   > **Bochner's Theorem.** The formula $m(a) = \int_{\hat A}\chi(a)\,d\mu(\chi)$ defines a bijection between
   >
   > - all bounded regular non-negative Borel measures $\mu$ on $\hat A$,
   > - all extendable positive linear functionals $m$ on $A$.

   Here *extendable* means: $m$ can be extended to a positive linear functional on the $^*$-algebra $A_1$ obtained by adjoining a unit (if one wasn't present) to $A$.
4. Bochner's Theorem does *not* require that $A$ be a **C$^*$-algebra**. If it is, then $\smash{\hat A = A^\dagger}$ and every positive linear functional $m$ is extendable, but not otherwise (ibid., pp. 391, 475).

Comment: One could adopt a definition of state on a unital algebras as being: $\psi(1)=1=\Vert\psi\Vert$ (I think that for unital Cstar algebras this is equivalent, by Hahn-Jordan decomposition?)